Why are there 2 stacks of insulators for some power cables?
I am looking at attachments of power cables to poles. I believe I understand what's going on in situations like this:

There are insulators between the cables and  horizontal wooden bar. 1 insulator stack of discs for each power cable. However, situations like this seem more complicated:

What's going on here? Why are there 2 stacks of insulators for each power cable?

Speculation: the connection at the pole slightly crushes the wire creating a weak point. The second wire is a parallel path.
